# By what logic, should instance constructors have access to static fields

Tags: c#, constructor

I was wondering why do instance constructor have access to static fields? If I initialize static fields via static constructors, and by mistake again initialize them through instance constructors, then the second initialization overwrites the first one. What is the idea behind making them accessible through instance constructors? (Please have a look at the simple program below to understand my point)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Circle C1 = new Circle(5);
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the first circle is {0}", C1.CalculateArea());
    }
}

class Circle
{
    public static float _Pi;                            // Since the value of pi will not change according to circles, we have to make it static
    int _Radius;                                        // This is an instance field, whose value is different for different instances of the class

    static Circle()                                     // A static constructor initializes the static fields        
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static constructor executed");
        Circle._Pi = 3.14F;
    }
    public Circle(int Radius)                           // An instance constructor initializes the instance fields 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance constructor executed");
        this._Radius = Radius;
        Circle._Pi = 2.12F;                             // This again initializes the value of the pi to a different value as given by the static constructor
    }
    public float CalculateArea()
    {
        return this._Radius*this._Radius*Circle._Pi;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `const` which makes it unwritable.

Comment: Daniel that's not the point of my question. There are other ways I can make my static field unwritable. My concern is why is this functionality provided..?? Like in what example, would an instance constructor need to use a static field??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of a use case where a constructor could want access to static members is when a static field  contains a counter of instances for a class. You may want a class member to get, retain (in a non-static field), and increment this counter which would be static.  Any time in the future that instance will have its own unique identifier.

Example:

```
public class Employee {
      static int NextEmployeeId;  // a counter across all employees

      public int EmployeeId;  // this instance's employee id
      public string Name;     // this instance's name.

      static Employee() {
          Employee.NextEmployeeId = 1;  // first employee gets 1.
      }

      public Employee(string Name) {
           this.Name = Name;
           this.EmployeeId = Employee.NextEmployeeId++;  // take an id and increment for the next employee
      }

}
```

Comment: Sir can you explain your answer with an example.?? Just to be sure that I understood the same thing that you are trying to explain :P

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are accessible from everywhere, even from constructor, or even from Main/other class. The purpose is that you will have only one static property/ field singleton for the whole app.

```
public class AClass()
{
   public static float staticField;
   public float field;
   public AClass()
   {
       staticField = 5;
       field = 6;
   }
   static AClass()
   {
       staticField = 7;
   }
}

public int Main()
{
     float initially = AClass.staticField; // initially this staticField is 7.
     AClass aclass = new AClass(); // instantiating AClass
     float localfield = aclass.field; // this field does not affect anyone. It is 6
     float newStaticField = AClass.staticField; // Due to previous instantiation, the value is now 5.

}
```

And I agree with you that in your example it is bad. Why? Because why would you change the value of Pi, since it is already determined and fixed, there is no reason to change the value of Pi in the constructor.

You probably need to know how to design class and get to know why you want to have the static field in the first place. Here is an example of a class which does it correctly having a static field (sort of... for example, because the Key should be hidden supposedly. This is just to show you how static field is useful and ok.):

```
public class NewEncryptionClass()
{
      public static string Key;
      public NewEncryptionClass()
      {

      }
      public NewEncryptionClass(string newKey)
      {
           Key = newKey; // store the key and keep it forever
      }
      static NewEncryptionClass()
      {
           Key = "key1"; // initially key is "key1"
      }
      public string Encrypt(string str)
      {
          string result = string.Empty;
          result =  "adlasdjalskd" + Key + "ajlajfalkjfa" + str; // do the Encryption, I just made up
          return result
      }
}
```

Here, the purpose is that if you instantiate a NewEncryptionClass, you would want to save the key, so that the next time you do the encryption, you would always use the latest key without having to specify it everytime. For ex:

```
public int Main()
{
     string initialkey = NewEncryptionClass.Key;
     string result1 = new EncryptionClass().Encrypt("encryptThis"); // using key1

     // let's change the key
     string result2 = new EncryptionClass("key2").Encrypt("encryptThat"); // using key2
     string result3 = new EncryptionClass().Encrypt("encryptOther"); // still using key2


}
```

This is of course if I want to keep the latest key forever, if not, then this class design is wrong and you need to rewrite it for your purpose.